# Изменить название программы в уведомлении

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Накидал пример вот. Вывожу своё приложение в taslbar с помощью Notify_Icon, и выдаю всплывающую подсказку(уведомление). Но заголовок программы смущает..как изменить на что-то своё? У других уведомлений(других программ) такого не наблюдаю.

Comment: szInfoTitle попробуйте прописать. Или szTip...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов 
nid.szInfo == "test message"
nid.szInfoTitle == "test"
а szTip прописан, но это всплывающее сообщение при наведении на иконку..

Comment: Я бы попробовал записать версионный ресурс и указать имя приложения.

Comment: @Squidward можно подробности про "версионный ресурс"? Как это, с чем кушают?

Comment: @Range Ну та [фигня](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058.aspx), где свойства приложения указываются типа названия и версии. Если вы разрабатываете в VS, то это где-то в районе свойств проекта наверняка. Я не очень в курсе.

Comment: @Squidward сейчас активно покопаю..

Comment: @Squidward огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для тех, кто столкнулся с похожей проблемой:
Добавляем в файлах ресурсов ресурс Version.
В нём будет поле *FileDescription*.
Это то, что нам нужно. Для VS.